# Blender 2.8: How to use image sequence as a texture?

Tags: texturing

I wish to use an image sequence as an animated texture on an object (if possible).
For example: I have image01.png, image02.png and image03.png and I wish to apply those as a texture on an object, while they work as an animated image sequence prefereably looped, if possible.I use Blender 2.8.

So what I seek is an image sequence on an object (UV wrapped), which is not a plane.
Do you know if this is possible and how?

There is also alpha in the PNGs, but I guess that is not difficult to set up a transparency after the animated image sequence as texture works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to use the "*texture node*" configured as "*image sequence*".

In this example I've got `pic01.png, pic02.png, pic03.png and pic04.png` in the same folder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - that is exactly what I was looking for! :)