# I need the node texure image sequencer but i cant find that

Tags: texturing, node-editor

Can someone help me please?
I need to put the image texure sequence but i can't find that in the shader editor

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186911/blender-2-8-how-to-use-image-sequence-as-a-texture

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Image Texture* Node to play a Video/Image Sequence in a Material. Don't forget to set the *Frame Count* according to your footage, otherwise it will only show the first frame.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a `Texture Image Sequence` node, it's actually just a `Image Texture` node in which you load an image sequence.

If you press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in the shader editor, under the `Texture` category, you will see `Image Sequence` in second position:

[image: img sequence]

This will open the browser for you to select the first image of the sequence. Once you click the `Import Image Sequence` button, it will create an Image Texture node set up to read a sequence:

[image]

You could also just add an `Image Texture` node, load the first image of your sequence, change the `Source` parameter from `Single Image` to `Image Sequence`, adapt the sequence settings to yours and it would work the same. But it's faster with the other method ;)